# Loading and displaying an image on the canvas using scala.js

Tags: image, canvas, scala.js

I just started messing with scala.js and got stuck pretty early. I have no scala experience so I probably overlooked something simple. I try to display an image on the canvas. I tried:

```
var image:HTMLImageElement = new HTMLImageElement()
image.src = "pathToSource"
image.onload = { () =>
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 200, 200) //ctx is the canvas rendering context
}
```

The problem with this code is that onload doesn't seem to exist, even though I can find it here: https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-dom/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalajs/dom/raw/Html.scala#L1333

I also tried a few other methods like onloaddata but I cant figure out what the compiler wants from me:

```
var image:dom.raw.HTMLImageElement = new HTMLImageElement()
image.src = "/img/image.png"
image.onloadeddata = new js.Function1[Event, _]{
  def apply(v1: Event):Unit={
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,200,200)
  }
}
```

Anyone knows how to load and display an image with scala js?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of org.scalajs.dom are you using? It looks like `onload` was added [quite recently](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-dom/commit/3d5a32c462eecf296aedaec4c6227c06524d2d17), in version 0.8.2. That might be the source of your confusion. (I'm on version 0.8.0, and get the same error.)

For reference, the idiomatic Scala syntax for something like this would usually be something like:

```
image.onloadeddata = { evt:Event =>
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 200, 200) //ctx is the canvas rendering context
}
```

or possibly (in some cases, if there is ambiguity):

```
image.onloadeddata = { evt:Event =>
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 200, 200) //ctx is the canvas rendering context
}:js.Function1[Event, _]
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to create the image with `dom.document.createElement("img")`
and then use `onload` event on the created image, here is a working example:

```
val ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
  .asInstanceOf[dom.CanvasRenderingContext2D]
var image = dom.document.createElement("img").asInstanceOf[HTMLImageElement]
image.src = "/img/image.gif"
image.onload = (e: dom.Event) => {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 525, 600, 0, 0, 525, 600)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `=` operator right after `.onload`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I indeed made a typo writing this question on stackoverflow. However I still get get error "value onload is not a member of org.scalajs.dom.raw.HTMLImageElement"